# How to increment certain rows by 1 Python

Tags: python, rows, openpyxl, increment

I can't seem to figure out a way to increment ws2 cell values.  Right now when the for loop, loops through my files the data is just written over in the ws2 cells.  How I make it so instead of writing only to cell ws2 A2 it increments by 1 each time so it would then write to A3 next, same for ws2 D2 this increments by 1 each time so then it would write to D3 next etc.

```
import openpyxl as xl; 
import os
   
input_dir = 'C:\\work\\comparison\\NMN'
template = 'C:\\work\\comparison\\template.xlsx'
newFile = 'NNM_Comparison.xlsx'
  
  
  
  
files = [file for file in os.listdir(input_dir)
         if os.path.isfile(file) and file.endswith(".xlsx")]
  
for file in files:
    input_file =  os.path.join(input_dir, file)
    wb1=xl.load_workbook(input_file)
    ws=wb1.worksheets[0]

      
    wb2 = xl.load_workbook(template) 
    ws2 = wb2.worksheets[0] 
    ws2['A2']=ws['A1']
    ws2['D2']=ws['B4']
    ws2['E2']=ws['D4']

      
      
    output_file = (newFile)
    wb2.save(output_file)
```

Comment: First you need a counter variable.

Comment: Use `ws2.iter_rows(min_row=2, max_row=…)`

Answer (score 2):

Two things you need to do:

1. Open the template just once. Otherwise, each time through the loop, you're starting from the original template, not combining the results of each iteration.
2. Use a counter variable to change the row number you're writing to in `ws2`. You can use `enumerate()` when you're iterating over the file list, and then add an offset to those indexes.

```
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(template) 
ws2 = wb2.worksheets[0] 

for i, file in enumerate(files):
    input_file =  os.path.join(input_dir, file)
    wb1=xl.load_workbook(input_file)
    ws=wb1.worksheets[0]

    row = str(i + 2)
      
    ws2['A' + row]=ws['A1']
    ws2['D' + row]=ws['B4']
    ws2['E' + row]=ws['D4']
      
output_file = (newFile)
wb2.save(output_file)
```

Comment: Thank you everyone for the help.  All these options work perfect.  I'm new at python so it's always neat to see how many different ways this can be implemented.

Answer (score 0):

Is this working for you?

```
i = 0
for file in files:
    input_file =  os.path.join(input_dir, file)
    wb1=xl.load_workbook(input_file)
    ws=wb1.worksheets[0]

      
    wb2 = xl.load_workbook(template) 
    ws2 = wb2.worksheets[0] 
    ws2[f'A{i+2}']=ws['A1']
    ws2[f'D{i+2}']=ws['B4']
    ws2[f'E{i+2}']=ws['D4']
    
    i += 1
```

Comment: Why not just initialize `i=2` so you don't have to add 2 every time?

Comment: You could too, just a personal habit.

Comment: I do have a question if I don't use enumerate it still works fine if I use the option by Adrien Kaczmarek

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand your question. Did you ask if my solution works without the use of `enumerate`? Yes, it does.

Comment: Yes, it works without it just fine.  There was a comment saying I need a counter so they used enumerate.  But it works fine without enumerate, so why did they say I needed it?

Comment: `enumerate` is extremely useful when you need an item and its position in the list. Here the position could act as a counter. Because it is a very basic tool, it is one of the first thing we think about when we need an item and an integer in a loop. However, even if it works perfectly, it is not the main meaning of the enumerate function (because its meaning is to give us the position of the item, not a random counter to use somewhere else). I hope I have answer your question.

Comment: Is there away to look at ws and count how many times the value 0 occurs in column F starting at row 4 and going to the end, and paste that number into ws2?

Comment: @Kristenl2784 yes, there's a way. Write a loop that iterates through all the rows, checking if `ws['F' + int(row)] == '0'` and incrementing a counter.

Comment: I don't think I understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `enumerate()`:

```
wb2 = xl.load_workbook(template) 
ws2 = wb2.worksheets[0] 

for i, file in enumerate(files):
    input_file =  os.path.join(input_dir, file)
    wb1=xl.load_workbook(input_file)
    ws=wb1.worksheets[0]
      
    ws2['A' + str(i+2)]=ws['A1']
    ws2['D' + str(i+2)]=ws['B4']
    ws2['E' + str(i+2)]=ws['D4']      
      
    output_file = (newFile)
    wb2.save(output_file)
```